# vue router /:param with slashes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a router like this:

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/survey/:surveyHash',
      name: 'survey',
      component: Survey,
      props: true,
    },
```

In the component I'm trying to get `surveyHash` in props. The trouble is I can't do it when there are `/` slashes inside `surveyHash`.

Is there a solution in vue-router?

Comment: Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) `encodeURIComponent('cat/abc')` -> `cat%2Fabc`

Comment: But how? Where put this `encodeURIComponent` ?

Comment: you will need to encode it wherever you generate the URL

Comment: OK, so I need to speak to backend developer ;P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a [custom matching pattern](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters) in your route definition

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/survey/:surveyHash(.*)',
      name: 'survey',
      component: Survey,
      props: true,
    },
```

With this you will get the rest of the URL including slashes in `surveyHash`

Comment: @AdamOrlov keep in mind that this will match everything after, meaning you cannot use `/survey/{hash}/edit` for example

Comment: Thanks Derek, good point, but in my case this works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

There is more elegant solution. Vue router uses path-to-regexp module under the hood and it have solution for this out of the box

```
const regexp = pathToRegexp('/:foo*')
// keys = [{ name: 'foo', delimiter: '/', optional: true, repeat: true }]
```

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#zero-or-more

```
const regexp = pathToRegexp('/:foo+')
// keys = [{ name: 'foo', delimiter: '/', optional: false, repeat: true }]
```

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#one-or-more